# Is it ok to format bootable usb Pendrive after install finished ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu

Formating USB(pendrive) after installing done in Dell laptop.

Comment: in short yes. But sometimes it may happen that your pendrive will show less storage than expected. In that scenario just create filesystem again on pendrive.

Comment: Once i formatted  my bootable pendrive.After that my computer asked me to connect bootable USB and was not operating system on my computer so I am little scared to format it.

Comment: If you just unplug it and turn on your computer and no error is displayed then you can surely format that. But if any error is displayed then you need to worry. Just unplug pendrive and see what happens.

Comment: If you booted the usb `toram` you could even umount & format the USB right then

Comment: If you made the stick using Startup Disk Creator, you might have a hard time unmountingd the ISO9660 partition to format. you can use Disks to unmount and then GParted to reformat. mkusb should also work.

Comment: @Karel: I don’t think the "Duplicated" post you have chosen relates to this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Ubuntu 18.04 on your local hard drive from an USB stick, and the installation succeeded, first reboot your computer without the stick connected to check that everything is working fine, and if it is, **you can format your USB drive directly from your new ubuntu installation**, assuming you won't need to use it for installing Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

Often during install the grub bootloader gets put on the Installer pendrive rather than the HDD, in which case the pendrive needs to be plugged in to boot.

Try installing using "Something else", when you get to the partitioning stage.

Confirm that the HDD is chosen for bootloader location.